# SwiftUI and Combine - how to create a form that has the number of fields corresponding with user selection

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am creating a basic Rent Splitting app to learn about Swift UI and Combine. I want to have a home screen where the user selects the number of housemates they share with first, and then based on that selection, they are shown a form which has fields that correspond with this number. So far I have the HomeView:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct HomeScreenView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel){
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Welcome to Fair Rent!")
                Text("Please select how many housemates you live with:")
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .padding(5.0)
                    
                NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts())))
                {
                   Text("1")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts())))
                {
                   Text("2")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts())))
                {
                   Text("3")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts())))
                {
                   Text("4")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts())))
                {
                   Text("5")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts())))
                {
                   Text("6")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts())))
                {
                   Text("7")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeScreenView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeScreenView(viewModel: HomeScreenViewModel(Variables()))
    }
}
```

Based on which number they click, they'll be taken to the FairRentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct FairRentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: FairRentViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: FairRentViewModel){
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Enter the total monthly rent:")) {
                    TextField("Total rent", text: $viewModel.amount.totalRent)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Enter your monthly income:")) {
                    TextField("Your monthly wage", text: $viewModel.amount.myMonthlyIncome)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Enter your housemate's monthly income:")) {
                    TextField("Housemate's monthly income", text: $viewModel.amount.housemateMonthlyIncome)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                Section {
                    Text("Your share: £\(viewModel.yourShare, specifier: "%.2f")")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("FairRent")
        }
    }
}

struct FairRentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FairRentView(viewModel: FairRentViewModel(Amounts()))
    }
}
```

I want the rent to be based on salary. At the moment as you can see there's only one form field for a housemate's wage to be entered, not taking into account if there are several housemates. I want the number of those fields to correspond with the number that the user has selected on the HomeScreen. I am very new to SwiftUI and am not sure of the best way to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction please? I am trying my best to use Combine and confirm to an MVVM pattern.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SwiftUI is data-driven where views are generated based on data, you'd need a place to store each housemate's amount somewhere, say in an array in the view model. Then you'd loop over the array to generate the `TextField`s.

Here's a conceptual example:

```
class FairRentViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var incomes: [String]

   init(for housemates: Int) {
      self.incomes = Array(repeating: "", count: housemates)
   }
}
```

<sup>(I used a `String` as a simplification, so it's easier to bind to a `TextField` later on)</sup>

Then the view would loop over the array:

```
struct FairRentView: View {
   @ObservedObject var vm: FairRentViewModel

   var body: some View {
      ForEach(vm.incomes.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
          TextField("Housemate \(idx + 1)", text: self.$vm.incomes[idx])
      }
   }
}
```

Then in the parent view, you could instantiate `FairRentView` with the right number of households. Again, this is a simplification, as you might want to have a loop here too.

```
struct HomeScreenView: View {
   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
         VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(vm: FairRentViewModel(for: 2)) {
               Text(2)
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: FairRentView(vm: FairRentViewModel(for: 3)) {
               Text(3)
            }
            // .. etc
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @NewDev for your solution. Where does `housemates` in your `FairRentViewModel` come from?

Comment: That's how `FairRentViewModel` is instantiated by the `HomeScreenView`: e.g. `FairRentViewModel(for: 2)` and passed to the `FairRentView` view

Comment: Thank you @NewDev - I am receiving "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" this error, so was just wondering

Comment: Are you seeing it in my simplified example, or are you integrating it into your code?

Comment: I'm using your example and trying to integrate into my code

Comment: This question doesn't contain much information about your real `FairRentViewModel`. From your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151269/swiftui-combine-using-models-and-viewmodels-together), it has a property of type `InputAmounts`. You'd probably want to have `InputAmounts` to contain an array of housemates' incomes (currently it only has a single number). So, you might want to do something like: `FairRentViewModel(Amounts(for: 4))` and change the init of `InputAmounts`